# Downloading files from expo react native webView

Tags: react-native, pdf, webview, download, expo

I need to download pdf from the site I opened with webView. When I try this the application closes. Is there any way to do this? Do I need to add permission.

I am using expo. What I do is connect to a site with the webView. When you press the download button on the site it downloads base64 as pdf. I can do this on the Internet. I did it in Chrome. However, I could not do it in the mobile application. How can I do that. When I click the button, the application closes. I’m getting this warning on the console `Can’t open url: data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNCAwIG9iag…` I can view but not download

Comment: have you solved this problem?

Comment: no, instead i sent the file via e-mail @JomarTinga

Comment: I solved it now using file-saver package in react js